# How to convert object containing Objects into array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I transform this data structure:

```
const data = {
            0: {
                campaign_lead_id: 2,
                date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
                campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
                influencer_name: null,
                influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
            },
            1: {
                campaign_lead_id: 1,
                date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
                campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
                influencer_name: null,
                influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
            }
        }
```

to array of arrays, where first array contains key names, and other arrays contain key values, like this:

```
const CSVdata = [ 
            ['campaign_lead_id', 'date', 'campaign_name', 'influencer_name', 'influencer_email'],
            ['2', '2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00', 'IOT course fall 2017', null, 'test_user_1@2key.co'],
            ['1', '2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00', 'IOT course fall 2017', null, 'test_user_1@2key.co']
        ];
```

Comment: Can you show your first approach to solve it?

Comment: I've tried to do it with forEach and map methods, but unsuccessfully

Comment: Can you share that?  you're going to get a lot of help! :-)

Comment: you might find [Papa.parse](http://papaparse.com/) helpful

Comment: Nothing to share, I just tried to use those methods, but I don't think that they can help me in this particular case

Comment: Is this an exam you're trying to cheat on with the help of stackoverflow ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I think you might looking for.
Pass object to the `makeArray` function it will return the required array.

```
const data = {
            0: {
                campaign_lead_id: 2,
                date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
                campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
                influencer_name: null,
                influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
            },
            1: {
                campaign_lead_id: 1,
                date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
                campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
                influencer_name: null,
                influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
            }
        };
function makeArray(data){
var initialKeys = Object.keys(data);
var answer = [Object.keys(data[initialKeys[0]])];
      for(let i=0;i<initialKeys.length;i++) {
      answer.push(Object.values(data[i]));
}
return answer;
}
const CSVdata = makeArray(data);
console.log(CSVdata);
```

**Note** : Only valid for object of objects.

Answer (score 0):

User this code snippet:
Object.keys() function return an array containing names of the keys of the object. Object.values() return an array of values of the object.

```
var arraysOfarray = [
    Object.keys(data[0]),
    Object.values(data[0])
];

console.log(arraysOfarray);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to build arrays of values dynamically, I mean instead of  Object.values(data[0]) I need somehow to loop through all object of data

Comment: Yea, i show you key areas of the solution. can't you do it by your self because once you know main areas, it so much simple.

Answer (score 0):

**As you said:** Using `forEach`

- Get the keys using `Object.keys` method.
- For each iteration use `Object.values` function.

```js
const data = {
  '0': {
    campaign_lead_id: 2,
    date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
    campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
    influencer_name: null,
    influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
  },
  '1': {
    campaign_lead_id: 1,
    date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
    campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
    influencer_name: null,
    influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
  }
};

var array = [['campaign_lead_id', 'date', 'campaign_name', 'influencer_name', 'influencer_email']];
Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => array.push(Object.values(data[k])));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

## Resources

- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

I find papa parse quite helpful for this sort of thing. If you can restructure your data so that it's a list of objects within an **array** (notice how i use [ rather than { to create the **const data** ), then I think it can be done with a single line of code:

```js
const data = [
             {
                campaign_lead_id: 2,
                date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
                campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
                influencer_name: null,
                influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
            },
            {
                campaign_lead_id: 1,
                date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
                campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
                influencer_name: null,
                influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
            }
        ]
        
var new_data = Papa.parse(Papa.unparse(data,{header:true}))["data"];

console.dir(new_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.3.7/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use reduce like below

```js
const data = {
  0: {
    campaign_lead_id: 2,
    date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
    campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
    influencer_name: null,
    influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
  },
  1: {
    campaign_lead_id: 1,
    date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
    campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
    influencer_name: null,
    influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
  }
}

let arr = Object.keys(data).sort().reduce((a, b) => {
  a.push(Object.values(data[b]));
  return a;
}, [Object.keys(data[0])]);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
    0: {
        campaign_lead_id: 2,
        date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
        campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
        influencer_name: null,
        influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
    },
    1: {
        campaign_lead_id: 1,
        date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
        campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
        influencer_name: null,
        influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
    }
}

const csvData = (data) => {
    const docs = Object.values(data);
    return [Object.keys(docs[0])].concat(docs.map(d => Object.values(d)))
};

console.log(csvData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. It will work even if properties are in different order.

```js
const data = {
    0: {
        campaign_lead_id: 2,
        date: "2017-11-11T22:19:33.538000+00:00",
        campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
        influencer_name: null,
        influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
    },
    1: {
        date: "2017-11-09T20:43:26.953000+00:00",
        campaign_name: "IOT course fall 2017",
        campaign_lead_id: 1,
        influencer_name: null,
        influencer_email: "test_user_1@key"
    }
};

let csv = Object.values(data).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc.push(acc[0].map(title => cur[title]));
    return acc;
}, [Object.keys(data[0])]);

console.log(csv);
```